# Find first unique number from array

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to answer a test using C# and the question is to find the first unique number from a given array A of N integers. If there is no unique number in the array then return -1.

For example, if A = {4,5,4,6,5,5,3,8,6} then return 3
if A = {3,2,3,2,3} then return -1

Range of each element of array A is [0..1,000,000,000], and range of N is [1..100,000],

Expected worst-case time complexity - O(N*Log(N))
Expected worst-case space complexity - O(N), beyond input storage  
 I am able to write the below solution that uses a List variable to store the duplicate numbers when iterating through the array A.
 My questions are as follows:  
1. Is this solution meets the complexity requirement as mentioned above? 
2. Is there a better approach/algorithm of doing this in C#, without using LINQ?

```
 public int solution(int[] A)
    {

        if (A.Length == 1)
        {
            return A[0];
        }
        else if (A.Length == 2)
        {
            if (A[0] == A[1])
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                return A[0];
              }
        }
        else
        {
            List<int> duplicateList = new List<int>();

            bool isDuplicate = false;
            for (int index = 0; index < A.Length - 1; index++)
            {                    
                if (duplicateList.IndexOf(A[index]) == -1)
                {
                    isDuplicate = false;
                    duplicateList.Add(A[index]);

                    for (int searchIndex = index + 1; searchIndex < A.Length; searchIndex++)
                    {
                        if (A[index] == A[searchIndex])
                        {
                            isDuplicate = true;
                        }
                        if (isDuplicate)
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                        if (searchIndex == A.Length - 1 && isDuplicate == false)
                        {
                            return A[index];
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            if ((duplicateList.IndexOf(A[A.Length - 1])) == -1)
            {
                return A[A.Length - 1];
            }
            else return -1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your answer has a time-complexity of `O(n^2)` as can be easily inferred from the nested-loop structure, or even more depending on the implementation of the indexOf call in List.

Thus to optimize it to `O(nlogn)` you can use the Dictionary interface in C# to store the numbers and their frequencies of occurrence and their index in the array as Key,Value pairs and then traverse the Dictionary to find the first number in array with frequency of 1.

Comment: I have implemented your approach and tested it. In the worst-case scenario of array containing 1M numbers, the execution time for my earlier solution was 71 ms whereas for your solution it just took 48 ms. Thanks for your help and time.